# Python - Average all key values with same key to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I'm working with this dictionary:

```
ratings={'Shane': {'127 Hours': 5.0, 'Avatar': 4.5}, 'Jaycee': {'127 Hours': 4.8, 'Avatar': 3.5, 'Mad Max: Fury Road': 4.9}}
```

I'm trying to round all the same keys' values and output them as such:

```
ratings={'127 Hours': 4.9, 'Avatar': 4.0, 'Mad Max: Fury Road': 4.9}
```

Mad Max stays the same, as it's not in the first dictionary anywhere to get averaged with, while Avatar and 127 Hours get averaged with themselves and then combined in one key. What would be the best way to do something like this?

Comment: Show us your attempt.

Comment: Try to use `pandas`.

Comment: Pandas is an overkill here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nice approach to aggregate over a similar key is using a `defaultdict` with a `list`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

ratings= {
    'Shane': {'127 Hours': 5.0, 'Avatar': 4.5},
    'Jaycee': {'127 Hours': 4.8, 'Avatar': 3.5, 'Mad Max: Fury Road': 4.9}
}

# this creates a dictionary that sets a default value of an empty list on 
# access, which makes the aggregation a bit nicer since no 
# initialization is needed
by_movie = defaultdict(list)

# aggregate to the default dict
for name, mrs in ratings.items():
    for movie, rating in mrs.items():
        by_movie[movie].append(rating)

# calculate averages
averages = {movie: sum(movie_ratings) / len(movie_ratings) for movie, movie_ratings in by_movie.items()}

print averages
```

Output:

> {'127 Hours': 4.9, 'Mad Max: Fury Road': 4.9, 'Avatar': 4.0}

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the helpful comments too.

Answer (score 1):

```
ratings={'Shane': {'127 Hours': 5.0, 'Avatar': 4.5}, 
        'Jaycee': {'127 Hours': 4.8,
        'Avatar': 3.5, 'Mad Max: Fury Road': 4.9}}
result = {}

for _,value in ratings.items():
    for key,val in value.items():
        result.setdefault(key, []).append(val) 

print {i:sum(result[i])/len(result[i]) for i in result}
```

Output:

```
{'127 Hours': 4.9, 'Mad Max: Fury Road': 4.9, 'Avatar': 4.0}
```

Comment: May I suggest `collections.defaultdict(list)` instead of vanilla `dict.setdefault(...)`. Makes for cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

Because "functional" is always better and so on ;)

```
from itertools import chain, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

{k: (lambda g: sum(map(itemgetter(1), g)) / len(g))(list(g))
 for k, g in groupby(sorted(chain.from_iterable(map(dict.items,
                                                    ratings.values())),
                            key=itemgetter(0)),
                     itemgetter(0))}
```

output:

```
{'127 Hours': 4.9, 'Mad Max: Fury Road': 4.9, 'Avatar': 4.0}
```

Comment: Ah yes. Itemgetter. That's what I was looking for but wrote a lambda instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools, operator

d = {}

for movie, items in itertools.groupby(sorted(itertools.chain(*[x.items() for x in ratings.values()])), lambda x: x[0]):
     items = list(items)
     d[movie] = sum(x[1] for x in items)/len(items)
```

Gives you `{'127 Hours': 4.9, 'Mad Max: Fury Road': 4.9, 'Avatar': 4.0}`

I don't recommend it but what the heck. :)

Comment: Thanks for a smaller alternative answer!